# Como mixar parâmetros dentro de um Html.BeginForm ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte `Html.BeginForm`(Não leve em conta se está incorreto é um código legado e eu não consigo refatorar isso agora).

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Download", new { ContributorID = "exemplo"}, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "confirm" })) {
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="work_select">Selecione uma obra existente:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="work_select">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione uma obra</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p id="error-message"></p>

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <input type="submit" value="@MainMessages.confirm_your_download" class="button-download" style="width:100%" />
        <br />
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirm(string contributorID,string work_select)
```

Se vocês perceberam existe um parâmetro sendo adicionado sem a utilização de um input `new { ContributorID = "exemplo"}`, **preciso que isso continue assim**, porém o `<select>` não está passando o valor de `work_select` para o controller, ele chega `null`, como posso fazer para resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `<select>` não está sendo enviado pelo form poque ele não possui o atributo `name`. Enquanto `id` é importante para o JavaScript na estrutura do `DOM`, os controles do `<form>` só serão anexados aso `FormData` se eles indicarem o atributo `name` ou se você adicioná-los manualmente via JavaScript.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="work_select">Selecione uma obra existente:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="work_select" name="work_select">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione uma obra</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito Leandro, comi bola com isso... estou tão acostumado a usar o Helper do Razor que não lembrava dessa parte do HTML em sí.